# Monodevelop: "MSBuild process could not be started"

Tags: mono, monodevelop, mdtool

I just installed monodevelop on Arch Linux using pacman. I can compile with the mcs command, but I can not build in monodevelop. I am told "MSBuild process could not be started". The same error is given if I try building with mdtool on the command line.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem. I also installed Arch Linux today and am not able to compile in Mono Develop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the project options of your project in monodevelop. At Build -> General, there is a new option called `Use MSBuild engine (recommended for this project type)`. Uncheck this option.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to post [Bug 33896 - Build fails if LANG is set to a UTF8 locale](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=33896).

Basically you have to start monodevelop with something like *`LC_ALL=C monodevelop`* and you can use MSBuild.

Even better option is to enable non-utf8 locale for your region. Edit the content of *`/etc/locale.gen`* and un-comment your non-utf8 regional locale. Then run command

> locale-gen

to regenerate locales and

> locale -a

to verify that new locale is available. In my case (Slovenia) I then start monodevelop with

> LC_ALL=sl_SI monodevelop

Or you can disable MSBuild as described in previous answer.